# OCR in the Wild - Image preprocessing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tesseract

I'm using pyOCR and tesseract 4.0.0 to recognize text in images. It works pretty well but often it fails to correctly recognize "i" vs "l".

My preprocessing steps are:

- cv2.threshold(cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
- cv2.dilate(binimage, (3,3), iterations=1)

I also tried to convert to HSV, only threshold on the green color channel, erode, blur and unskew, but it seems to worsen the results.

[image: original image]
[image: after pre-processing]

How can i pre-process my images better to recognize Takabari instead of Takabarl

Comment: Have you tried using a dictionary to do post processing? Something like librespeech-vocab.txt found at http://www.openslr.org/11/? Using some form of non OCR post processing of the data, especially if you might have a good idea of the possible outputs, will probably be the fastest and most accurate way to resolve this problem.